# Laplacian of standard hermitian inner product on $C^n$.

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-geometry, laplacian, hodge-theory

Treat $C^n$ as a complex manifold, and consider the standard Hermitian metric $h = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^n dz_i d\bar{z}_i$, so that the corresponding J-invariant metric is $g = \sum dx_i^2+dy_i^2$, where $z=x+iy$. Define $\Delta = dd^{*}+d^{*}d : \Omega^{p,q} \rightarrow \Omega^{p,q}$, where $d^* = -*d*$, where $*$ is the Hodge operator.

I computed $\Delta(f) = -2 \displaystyle{\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial{}}{\partial{\bar{z_i}}}\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{z_i}}}$, but I was expecting the factor to be $-4$ at the front.

Here is my computation: Let $v = dx_1 \wedge dy_1 \wedge ... \wedge dx_n \wedge dy_n = C dz_1 \wedge d\bar{z_1} \wedge ...$ be the volume form, for some constant $C$. I believe $C = (i/2)^n$. Then, since $(d\bar{z_i}, d\bar{z_i}) = 2$ using the induced metric on the dual space, we get that $*dz_i = -2C dz_1 \wedge d\bar{z_1} \wedge ... \wedge dz_i \wedge dz_{i+1}\wedge d\bar{z_{i+1}} ...$ so

$\displaystyle{-*d*df = -*d* \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{z_i}} dz_i = 2C *d \frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{\bar{z_i}}} d\bar{z_i} \wedge dz_1 \wedge d\bar{z_1} \wedge ... \wedge dz_i \wedge dz_{i+1} = -2 \frac{\partial{}}{\partial{\bar{z_i}}}\frac{\partial{f}}{\partial{z_i}} * v}$, and $*v = 1$.

Comment: For starters, the Laplacian is a *second-order* differential operator. What you've written is a product of first derivatives.

Comment: Oh thanks, that was a typo

Comment: The rest is sloppily written, with forms left unwritten, etc. At any rate, the $4$ you’re thinking of comes from $$4\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial z\partial\bar z} = \dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}+ \dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial y^2},$$ but I believe the $2$ is the correct factor for the Laplacians.